# Connect washing machine drain pipe to existing outlet

Tags: pipe, washing-machine, uk

I am trying to install a washing machine next to our boiler. I don't have an SDS drill so I'm trying to get away with not drilling a hole in the cavity wall. There's an existing hole through the wall where the condensate from the boiler drains away into the waste pipe which goes to the soil pipe.

From what I've read online, it looks like I would need to have to put the washing machine drain in to a standpipe before the wastewater goes outside and I shouldn't go from a 40mm standpipe to a narrower flexible pipe because you should always flow through pipes getting larger, not smaller right?

Is there any way I can reuse this pipe through the wall for the washing machine waste water? Or is my only way of resolving this by drilling a 50mm hole in the cavity wall using tools I don't have at the moment?

[image]

Comment: Washing machine new type often need 2” pipe to handle the velocity and volume of water being pumped out. What is the size of the boiler drain pipe with the p-trap ?